# Convert an Array of ints to Date-Objects

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of ints that I would like to convert to date-type objects:

```
[[19480916 19480901 19480917 19480901 19480901 19481019]
 [19480917 19480916 19481019 19480922 19480922 19490902]
 [19481004 19480917 19481021 19480924 19481004 19501124]]
```

I have the following code that is supposed to iterate through the array and convert each number into a date object and append it to a new list:

```
Date_List = []
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
for s in myArray:
    date1 = datetime(year=int(s[0:4]), month=int(s[4:6]), day=int(s[6:8]))
    Date_List.append(date1)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.
```

Is there a way where I am able to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use `str()` to convert each of the numbers to string and [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to load a string into a `datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime

l = [
    [19480916, 19480901, 19480917, 19480901, 19480901, 19481019], 
    [19480917, 19480916, 19481019, 19480922, 19480922, 19490902], 
    [19481004, 19480917, 19481021, 19480924, 19481004, 19501124]
]

for sublist in l:
    print([datetime.strptime(str(item), "%Y%m%d") for item in sublist])
```

Prints:

```
[datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 19, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 19, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1949, 9, 2, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1950, 11, 24, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: I tried this and I ended up getting an error that cannot be resolved no matter what: `for sublist in l:
    for item in sublist:
        print([date(int(item), '%Y%m%d')])`  would always yield TypeError: an integer is required (got type str). I also used "date" instead of datetime.strptime since the time is irrelevant to what I am doing.

Comment: @CyclonicLife sorry, I don't see you are using what I've proposed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because first of all you are trying to pass a slice of the list as parameters to `datetime()`

In your for loop, `for s in myArray`, each iteration of `s` looked something like this: `[19480916, 19480901, 19480917, 19480901, 19480901, 19481019]`

So when you tried passing in `s[0:4]`, you were actually putting `[19480916, 19480901, 19480917, 19480901]` into the `datetime(year: int)` parameter, and so on.

If you start to iterate over each number in the array that you were previously trying to pass in, the next problem is that integers cannot be sliced, so you must make each date string into a `str` before slicing, then cast it to an `int` as you were.

See my example:

```
myArray = [[19480916, 19480901, 19480917, 19480901, 19480901, 19481019],
           [19480917, 19480916, 19481019, 19480922, 19480922, 19490902],
           [19481004, 19480917, 19481021, 19480924, 19481004, 19501124]]

Date_List = []
for array in myArray:
    for string in array:
        s = str(string)
        date1 = datetime(year=int(s[0:4]), month=int(s[4:6]), day=int(s[6:8]))
        Date_List.append(date1)
```

and the output that I get:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(Date_List)
[datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 22, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1949, 9, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 21, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 9, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1948, 10, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1950, 11, 24, 0, 0)]
```

Which can also be printed in string format:

```
>>> pprint([str(d) for d in Date_List])
['1948-09-16 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-01 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-17 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-01 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-01 00:00:00',
 '1948-10-19 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-17 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-16 00:00:00',
 '1948-10-19 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-22 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-22 00:00:00',
 '1949-09-02 00:00:00',
 '1948-10-04 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-17 00:00:00',
 '1948-10-21 00:00:00',
 '1948-09-24 00:00:00',
 '1948-10-04 00:00:00',
 '1950-11-24 00:00:00']
```